# Proof of an identity of the Bessel function

Tags: functions, derivatives, bessel-functions

Could someone just give me a hint for this one? I'm simply stuck on how to get *anything* out of the grips of that derivative:

[image]

For reference:

[image]

Also, why can't we simplify this part:

$$x^n \left ( -\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx} \right )^n \to \left ( -\frac{d}{dx} \right )^n$$

??

Comment: use $e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i \sin(x)$

Comment: you can't simplify as in the last line, because you have a power of the operator, i.e. you will have the operator applied to your $\frac{1}{x}$ as well

Comment: Ohhhh right, I keep thinking that you can just raise all of the terms inside the parentheses to the $n$ power.

Comment: for better understanding of the last line you can just try to find $\Big( -\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \Big)\Big( -\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \Big)$ first. That should help!

Comment: Wait, in regards to my main question - you can distribute an operator into a sum, even if it's applied $n$ times right?

Comment: in this case, yes, since your operator is based on the derivative

Comment: Oh, that makes this pretty simple then. Ok thanks!!